# IDEA: How to re-wire a child to another parent POM?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

My project structure is currently the following:

```
master
  - project1
  - project2
  - project3 ...
```

Now, I have different sets of projects with different dependencies. I now want to have a structure like this:

```
master
  - dep1-submaster
      - project1
      - project2
      - project3
  - dep2-submaster
      - project4
      - project5
      - project6
```

I.e. I need to move `project1...project3` to another `master`. In Eclipse, I could simply open the POM editor, add the projects to the "new" master and would be asked if I wanted to update the parent section in the child POMs, too. However, I could not find such an option in IDEA.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this, other from doing it manually?

Comment: I suggest to do it manually, it sounds like a one-off operation and will take all of 2 minutes. A POM editor actually sounds scary to me... you will avoid alot of potentail problems by not placing your trust in tools like that.